# Document/Encoded and RPC/Encoded combinations are not WS-I compliant

Tags: web-services, soap, encoding, ws-i, standards-compliance

Can someone of this network explain why the Document/Encoded and RPC/Encoded encoding style combinations are not WS-I compliant into Soap-based web service?

Comment: Why not look at the standard?

Answer (score 0):

Document/Encoded and Rpc/Encoded are released by WS-I adheres bp1.0(basic profile 1.0) specification.

Later WS-I  release bp1.1,2.0.. specifications.The rules specified in these specification will not be supported by above message exchanging formats and also not complaint.

The only exchanging formats that are complaint to WS-I are Document/literal,Rpc/literal,Document/Wrapped